# How to pass the jquery values to HTML5 progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here i am trying to get the `html5` progress bar with values passed from jquery.

Here i have one for loop to count till 100, now i want to pass the values from values from 1 to 100 to `html5` progress bar. how can i do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
for ( var i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
alert(i);
}
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<progress value="55" max="100">
</progress>
</body>
</html>
```

When i run the web page. the progress bar should show progress from 1 to 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
for ( var i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
  document.getElementById('MyProgress').value = i; 
}
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<progress id="MyProgress" value="55" max="100">
</progress>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `setInterval` function for slow progress changing

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var val = 0;
    var interval = window.setInterval(function(){
        $("progress").attr("value", val);
        val++;
        if (val > 100) window.clearInterval(interval);
    }, 200);
});
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp